# First new line is ignored by Razor in TextArea fields

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

New lines at the start of html fields seem to be ignored by razor.

For example the following new line is ignored.

```
@{
    var value = "\r\nText";
}

<textarea>@value</textarea>
```

However if I add a space before the new line, the new line is no longer ignored.

```
@{
    var value = " \r\nText";
}

<textarea>@value</textarea>
```

How can I get the first new line to show without included a space before it?

Comment: How about manually inserting unicode data?
`&#xCODE;` allowing to insert unicode symbol. `CR+LF` must be a `&#x000D; &#x000A;` combination.

Comment: If you use the html helpers then it will render correctly - @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.yourProperty). Note its an issue with the browsers html parser (some discussions [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60484))

Comment: try `<textarea>@Html.Raw(value)</textarea>`

Comment: @Html.Raw(value) still ignores the first new line.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following html helper fixes the problem.

`@Html.TextArea("Name", value)`

Browsers seem to ignore the first new line due to textarea's commonly being written as:

```
<textarea>
   Value
</textarea>
```

Comment: [HTML Text](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/struct/text.html) : A line break occurring immediately following a start tag must be ignored, as must a line break occurring immediately before an end tag. This applies to all HTML elements without exceptions. In addition, for all elements except PRE, leading white space characters, such as spaces, horizontal tabs, form feeds and line breaks, following the start tag must be ignored, and any subsequent sequence of contiguous white space characters must be replaced by a single word space.